# Read Line By Line Until Integer is Found C

Tags: c, string, file, file-io, int

Trying to create a program that takes in a text file and reads it line by line. It then finds the two integers that are on each line and adds them together. It then outputs the new line with the original string and total to a new text file. I need help adding the two integers, getting them from each line, and then putting the new line to a text file.

input text file

```
good morning hello 34 127
ann 20 45
10 11
fun program and you find the same 90 120
news paper said that 56 11
how do you like 20 5
line number 90 34
```

Outputs first like would look like: and then continue on

```
good morning hello 161
```

Code:

```
int processTextFile(char * inputFileName, char * outputFileName)
{
   FILE *fp = fopen(inputFileName, "r");//open file to to read
   char buff[1024];
   char *p, *p1;
   int num;
   while (fgets(buff, 1024, fp)!=NULL)
   {
      printf("%s\n", buff);
      while(scanf(buff, "%*[^0-9]%d", &num)== 1)
         printf("%d\n", num);
      //fscanf(fp, "%s", buff);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

EDIT!!!!::

So now that I've been able to accomplish this. How would I sort it by the number produced? for example:

```
Time is money 52
here I am 3
21
```

Would output to a new text file in order like

```
here I am 3
21
Time is money 52
```

Comment: Suggestion: check for `fopen()` success

Comment: ..and, if the fopen() is sucessful, close the file at the end when you're done with it.  I would strtok() out each token and then attempt an integer conversion.

Comment: Edited with new question.

Comment: Write new questions as new questions. Editing an old question that already has answers is a good way to make the question unseen by us.

Comment: To answer new question: instead of printing inside the loop add the data to an array. When the loop finishes sort the array and only after all this print it.

Comment: @pmg how would I do that? Add the entire line to the array & only have it sort the integers that the end of each?

Comment: Ask a new question, kids. Ohhhh, I see you already did.

Answer (score 2):

My version using [`strcspn()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strcspn.html) is supposed to work with *stdin* for input and *stdout* for output. (so you can do `executable <textfile >newtextfile`)

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char line[1000];
    while (fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin)) {
        char *ptr;
        size_t x = strcspn(line, "0123456789");
        if (line[x]) {
            errno = 0;
            int n1 = strtol(line + x, &ptr, 10);
            if (*ptr && !errno) {
                errno = 0;
                int n2 = strtol(ptr, &ptr, 10);
                if (*ptr && !errno) {
                    int n3 = n1 + n2;
                    printf("%.*s%d\n", (int)x, line, n3);
                } else {
                    printf("%s", line); // line includes ENTER
                }
            } else {
                printf("%s", line); // line includes ENTER
            }
        } else {
            printf("%s", line); // line includes ENTER
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The same version without the error checking

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char line[1000];
    while (fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin)) {
        char *ptr;
        size_t x = strcspn(line, "0123456789");
        int n1 = strtol(line + x, &ptr, 10);
        int n2 = strtol(ptr, &ptr, 10);
        int n3 = n1 + n2;
        printf("%.*s%d\n", (int)x, line, n3);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The approach should be:

1. open two files, one for input, one for output.
2. use [`sscanf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf) to read the input buffer.
3. scan the leading string, and then **two** number.
4. if previous `sscanf()` fails, only check for **two** number.
5. if either of the above scanning is success, print the sum to the output file.

A sample code, should look like

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{

        FILE *fpin = fopen("ipfile", "r");//open file to to read
        if (!fpin)
        {
                printf("Error in ipfile opening\n");
                exit (-1);
        }
        FILE *fpout = fopen("opfile", "w");//open file to to write
        if (!fpout)
        {
                printf("Error in opfile opening\n");
                exit (-1);
        }
        char buff[1024] = {0};
        char str[1024] = {0};
        int num1 =0, num2= 0;
        while (fgets(buff, 1024, fpin)!=NULL)
        {
                memset(str, 0, sizeof(str));
                //printf("%s\n", buff);
                if(sscanf(buff, "%[^0-9]%d %d", str, &num1, &num2)== 3)
                    fprintf(fpout, "%s %d\n", str, (num1+num2));
                else if (sscanf(buff, "%d %d", &num1, &num2)== 2)
                    fprintf(fpout, "%d\n", (num1+num2));
        }

        return 0;
}
```

---

Note:

The above procedure, is a kind of *workaround*. If the data pattern in the file changes, lot of changes will be required to maintain a code like that. Instead of usinf `sscnaf()`, for a better and roubust approach, you should

1. read the line from file
2. start tokenizing the input buffer ([`strtok()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok)) and check for `int`s as tokens ([`strtol()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok)).
3. save the returned tokens and `int`s seperately.
4. once the `strtok()` returns NULL, you print the string tokens and the sum of the ints to the o/p file.

Answer (score 0):

I intend not to change your code completely, so I just added some snippets for improvement.

```
int processTextFile(char *inputFileName, char *outputFileName) {

     FILE *fp = fopen(inputFileName, "r");
     FILE *out = fopen(outputFileName, "w");
     char line[1024];

     if (!fp) {
          perror(inputFileName);
          return;
     }

     while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) != NULL) {
          int num1 = 0, num2 = 0;
          char textPart[1024] = "";
          if ( !sscanf(line, "%[a-zA-Z' ']%d%d", textPart, &num1, &num2) {
               sscanf(line, "%d%d", &num1, &num2);
          }
          fprintf(out, "%s %d\n", textPart, num1 + num2);
     }
     fclose(fp);
     fclose(out);
}
```

**Explanation:**

I scanned the text file, extracted the text part and the two `ints`. Since I noticed that the `ints` are placed at the end of each line, I just used `sscanf()` for that matter.

```
sscanf(line, "%[a-zA-Z' ']%d%d", textPart, &num1, &num2);
```

Here, `"%[a-zA-Z' ']%d%d"` format specifiers means to get only alphabets and spaces.

Since it will only get letters and spaces, the line `"10 11"` in your input file won't be put to `num1` and `num2`. Because the code inspects first for a string containing letters and spaces. Since 10 and 11 are not of the qualified types, then the line is just skipped.

That's why I added an `if-else` statement, which checks if sscanf wrote anything to memory. If sscanf returned 0, then it means that no text part is present. Just digits. So the program will scan the two digits.

```
if ( !sscanf(line, "%[a-zA-Z' ']%d%d", textPart, &num1, &num2) ) {
    sscanf(line, "%d%d", &num1, &num2);
}
```

I also added file checking for input file. It checks if file doesn't exist or can't be opened by the filestream.

```
if (!fp) {
      perror(inputFileName);
      return;
}
```

Here is the content of output file after execution:

```
good morning hello  161
ann  65
21
fun program and you find the same  210
news paper said that  67
how do you like  25
line number  124
```